# What is the overall state of the Mithraic/Atheist space fleet?

Tags: raised-by-wolves

In [*Raised by Wolves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_by_Wolves_(American_TV_series)), the two factions of Mithraists and Atheists have fought a war. Both seem to look into interstellar colonization, but they follow different approaches:

- The Mithraists use slow, large ships with human colonists in stasis.
- The Atheists use fast, small ships with a small android crew that is supposed to raise human children transported as embryos.

As noted early on in the series, the Mithraists consider the colonization method used by the Atheists as objectionable, based on their beliefs.

This all seemed to make sense at first ... until the series progressed and the dialogue appeared to suggest that rather than general methods of colonization of the two factions, what we're seeing are one-off efforts of either side. Especially when Mother taps into her pre-flight memories, it appears as if, rather than an organized faction that pursues colonization projects, the mission was more like the one-time culmination of a tech-savvy individual's pet project. Likewise, rather than any kind of a fleet, it now seems like the Mithraic ark ship was a one-of-its-kind thing.

On the other hand, plot logic/storytelling appears to point to the opposite:

- How could the Atheists hope to establish any kind of a colony if all they ever sent was 12 human beings?
- Why would the Mithraists condemn the Atheists' raising of children by androids if it was a new, one-time thing?
- If space travel were so rare that even the two major factions in what must have been the defining global war of the time could only send out one colonization vessel each, why would the protagonists even try and pose as "regular settlers" toward the newly arrived Mithraic landing team at first?
- Likewise, while the Mithraists are quick to see through the act, their reactions come across more like "We have encountered some people here, which is not totally unusual, and we have concluded that these particular people must belong to the Atheist faction." rather than "We have managed to run into the one colony our arch-enemy has ever tried to establish."
- And lastly: If those ~15 Mithraists are all that's left of the Mithraic colonization fleet

  > after the ark ship has crashed

  why bother (both in-universe and out-of-universe)?

**Are we watching the only handful of people left of either side's colonization efforts, or do the characters on the show belong to organizations that are active in other places, as well?**

Comment: "Why would the Mithraists condemn the Atheists' raising of children by androids if it was a new, one-time thing?" When we're talking religious differences, once or constantly doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

> How could the Atheists hope to establish any kind of a colony if all they ever sent was 12 human beings?

Twelve initial colonists is only a problem because of the genetic bottleneck. However, the show features biotechnology allowing androids to bring embryos to term (among other feats such as levitating robots), so perhaps they have the tools to address the bottleneck issue.

> Why would the Mithraists condemn the Atheists' raising of children by androids if it was a new, one-time thing?

Androids raising the children on *this planet* was a new one-time thing, but the issue may have already come up on Earth. There are many orphan characters on the show, which is unsurprising for the wartime disaster setting. Perhaps the atheists regularly used androids for childcare, while the Mithraic condemned it.

> If space travel were so rare that even the two major factions in what must have been the defining global war of the time could only send out one colonization vessel each, why would the protagonists even try and pose as "regular settlers" toward the newly arrived Mithraic landing team at first?

In season 2, there are indeed additional atheist settlers who have arrived in a commandeered Mithraic ship. The atheist ship carrying the embryos may be a one-off, but the Mithraic ark destroyed in season 1 seems to be merely one of multiple attempts.

> Likewise, while the Mithraists are quick to see through the act, their reactions come across more like "We have encountered some people here, which is not totally unusual, and we have concluded that these particular people must belong to the Atheist faction." rather than "We have managed to run into the one colony our arch-enemy has ever tried to establish."

The show doesn't go into much detail about the interstellar space travel that occurs in its fictional universe, but we do know that the Mithraic colonists were in some kind of suspended animation for most of the journey. It is possible that the Mithraic landing team does not have all of the information about who else may have landed. Perhaps other ships could have overtaken the ark in transit (e.g. ships that left later but could travel faster), etc.

> And lastly: If those ~15 Mithraists are all that's left of the Mithraic colonization fleet, why bother (both in-universe and out-of-universe)?

Again, in season 2 we find out that there is at least one other ark that brought humans to the planet. It seems that the Mithraic landing team could have been trying to prepare for future arrivals, at the very least. Also, they believe that a divine being is taking care of them, so perhaps no obstacles or circumstances would ever really be seen as hopeless.